# $(window).scrollTop() returnig 0

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently trying to get something to trigger when a div is close to the top of the window with the following code within document.ready however wScroll is always returning 0 I have checked that html, body tags do not how height:100% have attached to them which they don't any ideas where I am going wrong?

```
var wScroll = $(window).scrollTop();
console.log(wScroll);
if($('#about-me').offset().top < wScroll) {
    alert("wi");
    $('#about-me').html("Working");
    console.log("working");
}
```

Comment: Are you at the top of the page when you call `scrollTop`?

Comment: @Mike C It is called on load at minute so when it loads I am  at top of the screen. What I want is when the about me section is close to the top of screen for an animation to trigger I thought the wScroll variable would to detect how far the user is down the page.

Comment: Okay, so if you're calling it when you're at the top of the screen, why would you expect it to be anything other than 0? Perhaps you should look into the [scroll event](https://api.jquery.com/scroll/) and handle your logic there. [Here's a very simple example](https://jsfiddle.net/gqgg6eds/) of how to combine `scrollTop` with the `scroll` event.

Comment: @Mike C Sorry very new to using jQuery would I need to wrap the code into scroll event ?

Comment: Yes. Also, something very fundamental that you need to understand is that when you call a function, you get the value from that function *as it is in that moment.* The variable you assigned it to doesn't automatically update as you go.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your code in the an `onScroll` event handler

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {...});
```